# Enum element definition?

Tags: c++, enums

```
struct imageInfo{

        enum SliceOrientation 
        { 
            XY_PLANE = 0, 
            XZ_PLANE = 1, 
            YZ_PLANE = 2, 
            UNCHOSEN = 3
        } 
        sliceOrientation;

        int xOnViewer;
        int yOnViewer; 
        std::string sourceName;
        int viewerWindowWidth;
        int viewerWindowHeight;
    };


int main()
{

    imageInfo image;
    image.sliceOrientation = UNCHOSEN;
}
```

Why does the compiler keep saying UNCHOSEN is not defined? Can you tell me what exactly I am doing wrong in constructing and using the `Enum` `SliceOrientation` as a member of the `struct` `imageInfo`? I meant to make this code for c++.

Thanks

Comment: `imageInfo::UNCHOSEN` is defined.  Or `::imageInfo::UNCHOSEN` That is the scope you have put `UNCHOSEN` in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SliceOrientation` is a nested type of `imageInfo` so you need to qualify its name outside that `struct`.  If you write

```cpp
image.sliceOrientation = imageInfo::UNCHOSEN;
```

in your `main`, it will compile.